# как сделать сообщение приветствия в ВКонтакте?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Мне надо, что бы когда человек первый раз заходил в переписку, бот отправлял сообщение о приветствии (желательно с именем человека)

Comment: Это делается в настройках самого сообщества-бота.

Answer (score 0):

API вконтакте не позволяет отследить когда человек смотрит переписку. Можно отследить когда он начинает писать или уже что-то отправил. Для отслеживания событий (ваш случай) API вконтакте так-же нужно иметь свой сервер.

Самый удобный вариант для этого - библиотека vk_api